# How to unload/kill Chrome browser tabs when they use too much memory?

Tags: google-chrome, memory, google-chrome-extensions

I'm already using [The Great Discarder](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/the-great-discarder/jlipbpadkjcklpeiajndiijbeieicbdh?hl=en) and [my OOM Killer](https://gist.github.com/CTimmerman/6d1fc20c3fb61ef0ba3e2d6de2c582ce), but today Chrome became unresponsive again due to [this Mirror page using 4 GB RAM:](https://www.mirror.co.uk/news/world-news/woman-breastfeeds-bodybuilder-boyfriend-every-8153936) [image: Mirror webpage 4GB RAM]

Closing that tab helped, and now my 16 GB Window 10 machine with the latest Chrome is chugging along fine again:
[image: Chrome session doing fine again.]

Is there another automatic way to detect and neutralize those tabs?

Comment: Try also [OneTab](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/onetab/chphlpgkkbolifaimnlloiipkdnihall/) and [Tab Hibernation](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tab-hibernation/pbdpajcdgknpendpmecafmopknefafha).

Comment: BTW, Firefox is implementing automatic unloading of tabs, though that doesn't help your original query on Chrome: https://www.ghacks.net/2021/09/10/firefox-will-soon-unload-tabs-to-cope-with-low-memory-and-reduce-crashes/ This must be a common issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that [only the Chrome dev channel](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/processes/) supports looping over tab memory usage, so i had to modify my external program:

[image: External Chrome process monitoring]